# Ubuntu boot error xX#

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-16.04

I've been developing on Hyperledger Composer over the past few days, everything seemed fine. But since yesterday, I've been getting this error related to xX#, which totally slows down my Ubuntu. It's a brand new laptop, dual booted, and had perfect specs yet Ubuntu is pretty slow.. Attached link for the picture.

[image: https://ibb.co/fxLMJc]

#### Transcription

> Error found when loading /home/prashanth/.profile:
>
> /home/prashanth/.profile: line 1: xX#: command not found
>
> As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
>   
>   You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.

Comment: A screen shot of an error message isn't really helpful. Please transcribe the text from the dialog box. Did you read what it actually tells you?

Comment: What's actually in `/home/prashanth/.profile`?  I suspect that if you remove the `xX` from the very beginning of the file, the problem might go away.

Comment: @Deltik there's nothing at prashanth/.profile.
Also i have to tell you that it comes as a pop-up the moment i login.

Comment: @tripleee I'll do that.
It says:
Error found while loading /home/prashanth/.profile:
/home/prashanth/profile: line 1: xX#: command not found
Hope this helps.

P.S.: I've read what it tells me, plus i've googled and tried whatever i knew to resolve this. Yet it didn't help. That's why i've approached superuser :-)

Comment: It points to the file `.profile` in your home directory `/home/prashanth` which contains an error which you need to fix by editing. In the worst case, rename this file until you can figure it out properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I guess happened:

1. You opened `nano /home/prashanth/.profile` to edit something.
2. You didn't quite understand `nano`'s instructions to exit the program.  It says [image].
3. You then tried <kbd>x</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to no avail, not realizing that it was writing `xX` to the beginning of the file.
4. Finally, you put in the correct combination, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.
5. Instead of discarding your changes with <kbd>n</kbd>, you saved the changes with <kbd>y</kbd>.
6. Now, your `~/.profile` file has `xX#` on the first line which now looks like: `xX# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.`

To fix this, all you have to do is open up `~/.profile` (also known as `/home/prashanth/.profile`) and erase the `xX` at the beginning of the file.

Instructions using `nano`:

1. Run this command: `nano ~/.profile`
2. Press these key combinations:

   1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> ― Moves the cursor to the beginning of the file
   2. <kbd>Delete</kbd> ― Removes the character at the cursor, `x` in your case
   3. <kbd>Delete</kbd> ― Removes the character at the cursor, `X` in your case
   4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> ― Exit `nano`
   5. <kbd>y</kbd> ― Confirm that you want changes saved

The problem should now be fixed.